# FQL get feeds from multiple users

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I need to retrieve the wall posts of multiple Facebook Users . So far, I manage to retrieve the data from just one User but I need to get it from 60 users aprox. Here is my FQL query in objective C, I understand the query sintax is the same in every language:

```
[fql.parameters setObject:@"SELECT message,attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id in 
(SELECT id from profile where username = 'zara' )" forKey:@"q"];
```

Please I need help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looking for updates in an array of usernames:

```
SELECT message,attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id in 
 (SELECT id from profile where username IN ('zara','zuck','theuncrunched','thepaulcarr'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not getting the wall posts of the 4 users. Instead it is returning  just 2 or 3 posts from the first one. Which is the maximun number os results to display for every query?

Comment: The `stream` table is hobbled, and gives very little results. Try adding `LIMIT 100` to the end of the query. Don't forget that you have to be friends with the usernames you are listing to see their posts.